# Login required error when attempting to use the YouTube API

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api, google-api-php-client, youtube-data-api

I am trying to setup a script that can create live events via the YouTube API and I have taken the example off the [developer console](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/code_samples/php#create_a_broadcast) and attempted to modify it to use the API key instead as it will be going to our own account and not users using it for their own account.

Also, FYI I am using the [Google API PHP Client V1](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/tree/v1-master).

I have the below code:

```
require_once 'includes/Google/autoload.php';
require_once 'includes/Google/Client.php';
require_once 'includes/Google/Service/YouTube.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("My Title");
$client->setDeveloperKey("xxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');

// Define an object that will be used to make all API requests.
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

try {
    // Create an object for the liveBroadcast resource's snippet. Specify values
    // for the snippet's title, scheduled start time, and scheduled end time.
    $broadcastSnippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_LiveBroadcastSnippet();
    $broadcastSnippet->setTitle('Test Broadcast');
    $broadcastSnippet->setScheduledStartTime('2017-01-30T00:00:00.000Z');
    $broadcastSnippet->setScheduledEndTime('2017-01-31T00:00:00.000Z');

    // Create an object for the liveBroadcast resource's status, and set the
    // broadcast's status to "private".
    $status = new Google_Service_YouTube_LiveBroadcastStatus();
    $status->setPrivacyStatus('unlisted');

    // Create the API request that inserts the liveBroadcast resource.
    $broadcastInsert = new Google_Service_YouTube_LiveBroadcast();
    $broadcastInsert->setSnippet($broadcastSnippet);
    $broadcastInsert->setStatus($status);
    $broadcastInsert->setKind('youtube#liveBroadcast');

    // Execute the request and return an object that contains information
    // about the new broadcast.
    $broadcastsResponse = $youtube->liveBroadcasts->insert('snippet,status', $broadcastInsert, array());

    // Create an object for the liveStream resource's snippet. Specify a value
    // for the snippet's title.
    $streamSnippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_LiveStreamSnippet();
    $streamSnippet->setTitle('Test Stream');

    // Create an object for content distribution network details for the live
    // stream and specify the stream's format and ingestion type.
    $cdn = new Google_Service_YouTube_CdnSettings();
    $cdn->setFormat("1080p");
    $cdn->setIngestionType('rtmp');

    // Create the API request that inserts the liveStream resource.
    $streamInsert = new Google_Service_YouTube_LiveStream();
    $streamInsert->setSnippet($streamSnippet);
    $streamInsert->setCdn($cdn);
    $streamInsert->setKind('youtube#liveStream');

    // Execute the request and return an object that contains information
    // about the new stream.
    $streamsResponse = $youtube->liveStreams->insert('snippet,cdn', $streamInsert, array());

    // Bind the broadcast to the live stream.
    $bindBroadcastResponse = $youtube->liveBroadcasts->bind(
        $broadcastsResponse['id'], 'id,contentDetails',
        array(
            'streamId' => $streamsResponse['id'],
        ));

    $htmlBody .= "<h3>Added Broadcast</h3><ul>";
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<li>%s published at %s (%s)</li>',
                         $broadcastsResponse['snippet']['title'],
                         $broadcastsResponse['snippet']['publishedAt'],
                         $broadcastsResponse['id']);
    $htmlBody .= '</ul>';

    $htmlBody .= "<h3>Added Stream</h3><ul>";
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<li>%s (%s)</li>',
                         $streamsResponse['snippet']['title'],
                         $streamsResponse['id']);
    $htmlBody .= '</ul>';

    $htmlBody .= "<h3>Bound Broadcast</h3><ul>";
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<li>Broadcast (%s) was bound to stream (%s).</li>',
                         $bindBroadcastResponse['id'],
                         $bindBroadcastResponse['contentDetails']['boundStreamId']);
    $htmlBody .= '</ul>';

} catch (Google_Service_Exception $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
                         htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
} catch (Google_Exception $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>An client error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
                         htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
}

?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bound Live Broadcast</title>
</head>
<body>
<?= $htmlBody ?>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I run it I get the error:

```
A service error occurred: Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts?part=snippet%2Cstatus&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx: (401) Login Required
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This operation may only be executed by a user authenticated via OAuth2, you can't create a broadcast using just your developer key. In this case you want to use your own account, so you'll need to obtain an Access Token which is valid for that account, preferably an "offline" one, so you can refresh it automatically once it expires, this way you'll only need to manually go through the consent screen once. Here's more on OAuth 2 flow:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/server-side-web-apps

EDIT: to be more precise, the flow should be something like this:

1. In a separate script, **you** go through the process of obtaining an offline Access Token - click through the consent screen and grant your application access to API on your account's behalf.
2. Store the obtained token for later use, for example save it in a flat file or a database. You only need to do those first two steps once, later your token can be refreshed automatically.
3. User enters the site and your script uses the previously obtained token to perform API operations. Everything happens server-side, without user's input.

Comment: I don't want to do it via OAuth as I want the broadcast to be able to be created in OUR account but by OTHER users actions.

Comment: @Brett But you *must* use OAuth for this operation. The user who triggers the operation doesn't necessarily neet to be the one, who authorizes the request. You need to get the Access Token (for your account using your application/key) and store it somewhere (flat file, some database etc.), then use it to authorize the request to API once the PHP script is fired by "external" user.

Comment: But what kind of access is the user given to our account then? Just to be able to set a broadcast and one time only (one-time access token?) - also at the moment the user has to go through the process of clicking links to authorize etc...... the user that triggers the request, can it be seamless for them or do they have to still go through a process?

Comment: No, *you* have to go through the process of obtaining Access Token in some other place (another script for example) and store that token for later use. Then when the user enters, you use that previously saved token (without user's knowledge) to reach API from your server and perform operations you intended. It's happening server-side, your user doesn't know what kind of access you're using for what.

Comment: Do you mind adding the info from your comments into your answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to be authenticate with Oauth2 service, you can read more code with this sample : https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php

Try this :

```
// Call set_include_path() as needed to point to your client library.
require_once 'includes/Google/autoload.php';
require_once 'includes/Google/Client.php';
require_once 'includes/Google/Service/YouTube.php';
session_start();

/*
 * You can acquire an OAuth 2.0 client ID and client secret from the
 * Google Developers Console <https://console.developers.google.com/>
 * For more information about using OAuth 2.0 to access Google APIs, please see:
 * <https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication>
 * Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project.
 */
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = 'REPLACE_ME';
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = 'REPLACE_ME';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');
$redirect = filter_var('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],
    FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect);

// Define an object that will be used to make all API requests.
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  if (strval($_SESSION['state']) !== strval($_GET['state'])) {
    die('The session state did not match.');
  }

  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  header('Location: ' . $redirect);
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

// Check to ensure that the access token was successfully acquired.
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
  try{

    // Create an object for the liveBroadcast resource's snippet. Specify values
    // for the snippet's title, scheduled start time, and scheduled end time.
    $broadcastSnippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_LiveBroadcastSnippet();
    $broadcastSnippet->setTitle('Test Broadcast');
    $broadcastSnippet->setScheduledStartTime('2017-01-30T00:00:00.000Z');
    $broadcastSnippet->setScheduledEndTime('2017-01-31T00:00:00.000Z');

    // Create an object for the liveBroadcast resource's status, and set the
    // broadcast's status to "private".
    $status = new Google_Service_YouTube_LiveBroadcastStatus();
    $status->setPrivacyStatus('unlisted');

    // Create the API request that inserts the liveBroadcast resource.
    $broadcastInsert = new Google_Service_YouTube_LiveBroadcast();
    $broadcastInsert->setSnippet($broadcastSnippet);
    $broadcastInsert->setStatus($status);
    $broadcastInsert->setKind('youtube#liveBroadcast');

    // Execute the request and return an object that contains information
    // about the new broadcast.
    $broadcastsResponse = $youtube->liveBroadcasts->insert('snippet,status', $broadcastInsert, array());

    // Create an object for the liveStream resource's snippet. Specify a value
    // for the snippet's title.
    $streamSnippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_LiveStreamSnippet();
    $streamSnippet->setTitle('Test Stream');

    // Create an object for content distribution network details for the live
    // stream and specify the stream's format and ingestion type.
    $cdn = new Google_Service_YouTube_CdnSettings();
    $cdn->setFormat("1080p");
    $cdn->setIngestionType('rtmp');

    // Create the API request that inserts the liveStream resource.
    $streamInsert = new Google_Service_YouTube_LiveStream();
    $streamInsert->setSnippet($streamSnippet);
    $streamInsert->setCdn($cdn);
    $streamInsert->setKind('youtube#liveStream');

    // Execute the request and return an object that contains information
    // about the new stream.
    $streamsResponse = $youtube->liveStreams->insert('snippet,cdn', $streamInsert, array());

    // Bind the broadcast to the live stream.
    $bindBroadcastResponse = $youtube->liveBroadcasts->bind(
        $broadcastsResponse['id'], 'id,contentDetails',
        array(
            'streamId' => $streamsResponse['id'],
        ));

    $htmlBody .= "<h3>Added Broadcast</h3><ul>";
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<li>%s published at %s (%s)</li>',
                         $broadcastsResponse['snippet']['title'],
                         $broadcastsResponse['snippet']['publishedAt'],
                         $broadcastsResponse['id']);
    $htmlBody .= '</ul>';

    $htmlBody .= "<h3>Added Stream</h3><ul>";
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<li>%s (%s)</li>',
                         $streamsResponse['snippet']['title'],
                         $streamsResponse['id']);
    $htmlBody .= '</ul>';

    $htmlBody .= "<h3>Bound Broadcast</h3><ul>";
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<li>Broadcast (%s) was bound to stream (%s).</li>',
                         $bindBroadcastResponse['id'],
                         $bindBroadcastResponse['contentDetails']['boundStreamId']);
    $htmlBody .= '</ul>';
    } catch (Google_Service_Exception $e) {
      $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
          htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
    } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
      $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>An client error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
          htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
    }

    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  } else {
    // If the user hasn't authorized the app, initiate the OAuth flow
    $state = mt_rand();
    $client->setState($state);
    $_SESSION['state'] = $state;

    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    $htmlBody = " <h3>Authorization Required</h3>
    <p>You need to <a href="$authUrl">authorize access</a> before proceeding.<p>
    "
    }
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Banner Uploaded and Set</title>
</head>
<body>
  <?=$htmlBody?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't want to do it via OAuth as I want the broadcast to be able to be created in OUR account but by OTHER users actions.

Comment: this is not possible